# When should var be used instead of declaring an explicit type?

Tags: c#

```
        var Id = from value in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                              select value;

        IEnumerable<int> ids = from value in Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
                              select value;



        foreach (var v in Id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var x in ids)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        }
```

Both will do the same job, but what is the difference?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Hover over `Id` in your IDE - it should tell you the type it is.

Comment: See [Use of var keyword in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41479/use-of-var-keyword-in-c-sharp) for some information.

Comment: They are exactly the same, var is strongly type but leaves the typing of the variable to the compiler.  In this case the compiler would choose the type IEnumerable<int> .  You could have fun creating some tests and seeing which one is more efficient in memory usage or access speed or whatever metric you chose, but they are the same.

Comment: I have to use large amount collection of data , which one is the efficient one, i have tried both of them for testing, but i haven't got any difference.

Comment: @MohammedBilal that's because there is no difference between them, `var` is just syntactic sugar so that you don't have to explicitly specify the type of the variable. the type will be inferred from the expression that follows the `=` operator.

Comment: This sort of question is exactly the reason why you should only use var where the type is made explicit by the right side of the assignment.

Comment: @LennyGodber unfortunately, 'explicit' isn't absolute. I'm sure I'm not the only person to whom it's entirely obvious what the type of `Id` is.

Comment: @LennyGodber: C# can be written without an IDE. It is not meant to be. The return type of a LINQ statement is irrelevant, and can get complicated. When writing you don't need type reminders because the static analyzer can tell you. When reading you don't need type reminders because the static analyzer can tell you. If you're reading idiomatic C# in notepad then you're gonna have some difficulties, but frankly that's true for all forms of type inference, and that doesn't make it a bad idea.

Comment: @AakashM, you have confused "explicit" for "implicit" there.

Phoshi, I am also a C# developer. Despite the capabilities of the IDE, I'd suggest that the confusion of the OP here speaks for itself. Hell, even the fact that no-one has pointed out that Enumerable.Range(0, 100) already emits an IEnumerable, rendering the select operation tautologous, suggests that there are benefits to explicit declaration.

var, however, definitely has very valid benefits when work with chained complex LINQ statements.

Comment: @LennyGodber: I'd argue that if we want to benchmark features on whether people who don't know the language understand them, it would be better to do so based on the average difficulties of all people, rather than one specific case. I'd wager that complex generic types are a significantly harder problem for your average person to understand than type inferencing is.

Comment: @LennyGodber the OP is confused because he didn't know `var` at all. Someone could be confused by encountering `else`, `using` or `try...catch` just the same. I'm not saying that one should use `var` everywhere they can, I agree that it can be abused, it's just that this question cannot be a justification for avoiding to use it.

Comment: @LennyGodber not sure I have, but never mind.

Comment: Take it into chat guys, comments aren't for extended discussion :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explicitly defining variable data types vs. using the keyword 'var'?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/42863/explicitly-defining-variable-data-types-vs-using-the-keyword-var)

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between the two, except for readability. The second example (ids) is more explicit than the first and perhaps more readable.  But, readability is a matter of taste/opinion with many different viewpoints.  Here are some guidelines...

```
 public void SampleCode()
        {
            //Use of var is encouraged when  declaration needlessly clutters code
            Widget widget1a = new Widget();  //No
            var widget1b = new Widget();  //Yes, I know I am getting a widget.

            //Use of var is encouraged when method name defines return type 
            //or return is type is known without further need of code inspection
            Widget widget2a = GetWidget(); //OK (Verbose)
            var widget2b = GetWidget(); //Yes, But...
            //Danger, Will Robinson!  if GetWidget returns a foo...Code review time!

            //Use of var is discouraged when method offers new clue to type 
            //without further code inspection
            Widget widget3a = Process(); //Yes, intent is clear without any further inspection.
            var widget3b = Process(); //No, What does Process do?
        }
```